# Remove Temporary key C# Windows 8 App

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

How do I Remove a Temporary key in a C# Windows 8 App? I downloaded a template that has one and got the error it expired. Do I need to put in a key of my own? I'm sure the author wont care its just the C# Windows Store Grid App XAML) Template that visual studios ultimate 2013 provides. The author just added a background image to show people how to do that. I removed his image and put in my own.

I'm a total noob at coding this is my first time using visual studios. All I understand atm is web design and adding snippets and changing values of code as well as compiling it.

I like to open, open source code to learn from it and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Within your solution, double-click on the "Package.appxmanifest" file. This should open up the "App Manifest Designer". Go to the Packaging tab. Click on the button labeled "Choose Certificate..." and choose a new certificate. Chances are you want "Create test certificate...". You don't need a password. Hit OK and you should be good to go.

If you're looking to sideload the app onto other machines at your workplace or upload the app to the app store, you've got quite a bit of other work to do -- but that is I think outside the scope of this question.